# Apache2, disable rewite in letsencrypt directory for all vhosts

Tags: virtualhost, mod-rewrite, apache2

Running Apache 2.4.7 (Ubuntu 14.04) with vhosts and letsencrypt certs. Many vhosts run WordPress which creates a `.htaccess` file. I had excluded the `.well-known` folder in a few of these `.htaccess` files but updates to WordPress or plugins regularly wipe these manual modifications.

It would be nicer to turn `RewriteEngine off` for this folder under each vhost, but this is proving difficult as doing so under the `<Location>` directive isn't supported. From what I'm seeing, the `<Directory>` directive has to be specific rather than relative?

What are my options? Given that I'm on Apache 2.4.7 I can live with adding `RewriteOptions Inherit` to each vhost config. But would like to avoid adding bespoke config to each vhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but updates to WordPress or plugins regularly wipe these manual modifications.

WordPress updates should only update code within the `# BEGIN WordPress` (or similar) comment markers. Although it's possible that some plugins don't play nice.

> the `<Directory>` directive has to be specific rather than relative?

Whilst the `<Directory>` directive maps to an absolute filesystem path, you can specify basic *wildcards* for path segments (`?`, `*` and character ranges `[]`). Or, optionally, use a full regex (with the addition of the `~` character). For example:

```
<Directory ~ "\.well-known$">
```

Reference:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory

Comment: Ah! Wasn't aware of the full regex, will have a play with that and report back. As the paths for the vhosts may vary in depth wildcards won't be a reliable option. Thanks. Now kicking myself for not spotting it on the documentation sites I was was reading earlier...